# Chatter Profile Based Rollout not working

Tags: community, chatter

I am trying to get hold on "Enable Chatter" permissions for profiles and permissions set, which get available once you are using "Chatter Profile Based Rollout" enabled org. 
I assume this chatter profile based rollout is now GA ([link](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/summer14/release-notes/rn_chatter_pbr.htm)) and should be enabled in all orgs by default.

But somehow I am not seeing the "Enable Chatter" permission on profiles. I tried disabling chatter and vice versa too, but no luck.

I specifically need it for communities, where only some users should have chatter access.

Any tips on how to make this chatter based roll out work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Profile based Chatter feature is GA but it is not available by default. You would need to open a case and request SF support to enable it for your org. One more very important aspect is that this is NOT available for Developer edition org. Which type of org are you trying it in? For a developer org you might need to escalate the case to Tier III and justify your need and then they will enable it. We got it enabled for a dev org as we had to implement this feature for our package which can only be created in a dev org. Hope it helps. :)

Regards
Kamal Ranjan

Comment: I need it for DE org, as we are developing an App. Thanks for help @Kamal, this is what I was looking for.